# Calculate inverse Laplace transform of $\exp(\sqrt{s^2-r^2})$

Tags: laplace-transform, fourier-transform, inverse-laplace

I have some trouble with the calculation of the inverse Laplace transform $e^{-k\sqrt{s^2-r^2}}$ , $k\geq0$, $r$ is known. ##

---

##
And I believe it has some relation with the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{e^{-k\sqrt{s^2-r^2}}}{\sqrt{s^2-r^2}}$ , but I find it hard to deal with the modified Bessel function $I_0$.

---

Hope some one can help me :).

Comment: Which variable do you want the inverse transform for, $s$ or $k$?

Comment: You could try the section starting from page 227 (242 in the pdf)
https://authors.library.caltech.edu/43489/1/Volume%201.pdf

Comment: The second transform you mention is in that book on page 249 (264 in the pdf). I can't see the first one you mention.

Comment: For $k > 0, \,r > 0$,
$$\mathcal L {\left[ I_0 {\left(r \sqrt {t^2 - k^2} \right)} H(t - k) \right]} =
\frac {e^{-k \sqrt {s^2 - r^2}}} {\sqrt {s^2 - r^2}}.$$
Differentiating wrt $k$,
$$\mathcal L {\left[
 \frac {r k \,I_1 {\left( r \sqrt {t^2 - k^2} \right)}} {\sqrt {t^2 - k^2}} H(t - k) +
 \delta(t - k) \right]} =
e^{-k \sqrt {s^2 - r^2}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

In the [book](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/43489/1/Volume%201.pdf) I mentioned in the comments there there are identities for $s=\sqrt{p^2-\alpha^2}$ where $p$ is the variable being inverse transformed. You should be able to relate the expression you know to the one you don't know through this.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. k and r are constant, and I think $\int_{0}^{t}I_0[\sqrt{a(t^2-u^2)}]f(u)$ is hard to calculate, so here is what I did:

Comment: (1) Let $F(s)=e^{-k\sqrt{s^2-r^2}}/{\sqrt{s^2-r^2}}$, $f(t)=I_0[r\sqrt{t^2-k^2}]u(t-k)$, then $L(F(s))=f(t)$, u(t) is the step function.

Comment: (2) $d(e^{-k\sqrt{s^2-r^2}})/ds$=($-ks/\sqrt{s^2-r^2}$)$*$$e^{-k\sqrt{s^2-r^2}}$=$-ksF(s)$, while $L(-ksF(s))$=$-kf'(t)$

Comment: (3) So, $e^{-k\sqrt{s^2-r^2}}=\int{\frac{d(e^{-k\sqrt{s^2-r^2}})}{ds}}ds$ -> $-kf'(t)/t$.

Comment: (4) So, my answer is $-kf'(t)/t=-k[I_0(r\sqrt{t^2-k^2})\delta(t-k)/t+\frac{r}{\sqrt{t^2-k^2}}I_1(r\sqrt{t^2-k^2})u(t-k)]$. Is there any calculation error?